# Codeigniter : Unable to locate the model you have specified

Tags: php, codeigniter, centos, hmvc

I have upgraded my PHP from version 5.2.9 to 5.3.1 and have encountered the following with my codeigniter application:

`Unable to locate the model you have specified: some_model`

Codeigniter version 2.1, with HMVC extension
Server: Centos 5

The model names are all in lower case and it is also loaded by calling their lower case letter. Everything used to work before the PHP upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HMVC, then you have to provide the module name as well.

Like this

```
$this -> load -> model('module/model_name');
```

Comment: Eg: Module name is 'module1'
Model name : some_model
Modle filename : some_model.php
How module is loaded: `$this->load->model('module1/some_model');`
So, I am using it as you mentioned. It has been working with my previous PHP version, but not with this one.

Comment: @Damchey, When you update your php, may be php.ini got overridden and settings where pushed back to default.

Comment: Pinpointed the problem. The `My_Loader.php` file was deleted somehow. Sorry.

Comment: @Starx,  I've same issue MY_Loader.php is still there. This is working fine in another module. What may be the reasons? Thanks

Comment: Yp Got it... Just renamed the module folder name. now it consist only lowercase alphabets

Answer (score 0):

Make the second parameter to TRUE:

```
$this->load->model('modelname', TRUE);
```